# Add custom thumbnail for facebook link share

Tags: facebook, youtube

so one of the functions of the site I am working on is a video blog... using YouTube embedded videos in the posts of the blog section.. and that is working quite nicely... However, when I go to share the post on FB to drive traffic it doesn't pull the thumbnail like it does from sharing this video from youtube.com itself. I know in the past I could add "link href" in my heard of a page to put a fixed custom thumbnail to be pulled... But I was wondering if you guys knew how I might accomplish that  Doing it dynamically would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this . add into your header.

```
   <link rel="image_src" href="http://www.myfavoritepic.jpg/" />
   <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.myfavoritepic.jpg/" />
```